# Setting Bash variable to last number in output

Tags: bash

I have bash running a command from another program (AFNI). The command outputs two numbers, like this:

`70.0 13.670712`

I need to make a bash variable that will be whatever the last # is (in this case 13.670712). I've figured out how to make it print only the last number, but I'm having trouble setting it to be a variable. What is the best way to do this?

Here is the code that prints only 13.670712:
`test="$(3dBrickStat -mask ../../template/ROIs.nii -mrange 41 41 -percentile 70 1 70 'stats.s1_ANTS+tlrc[25]')"; echo "${test}" | awk '{print $2}'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just [pipe(`|`)](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-4.html) the command output to `awk`. Here in your example, `awk` reads from `stdout` of your previous command and prints the `2nd` column de-limited by the default single white-space character.

```
test="$(3dBrickStat -mask ../../template/ROIs.nii -mrange 41 41 -percentile 70 1 70 'stats.s1_ANTS+tlrc[25]' | awk '{print $2}')"
printf "%s\n" "$test"
13.670712
```

(or) using `echo`

```
echo "$test"
13.670712
```

This is the simplest of the ways to do this, if you are looking for other ways to do this in `bash`-ism, use `read` command as using [process-substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst)

```
read _ va2 < <(3dBrickStat -mask ../../template/ROIs.nii -mrange 41 41 -percentile 70 1 70 'stats.s1_ANTS+tlrc[25]')
printf "%s\n" "$val2"
13.670712
```

Another more portable version using `set`, which will work irrespective of the shell available.

```
set -- $(3dBrickStat -mask ../../template/ROIs.nii -mrange 41 41 -percentile 70 1 70 'stats.s1_ANTS+tlrc[25]');
printf "%s\n" "$2"
13.670712
```

Comment: The `read` solution is pretty good and idiomatic. I would not recommend the `set` one; I guess the first one would be the best option if looking for portability (but OP specifies Bash, so we're safe to go with the `read` solution, that would be the most efficient).

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: Appreciate it! Wanted to provided as possible ways to do without external utilities. But I suppose for a trivial use case as this, it doesn't matter anyway. The reason for not recommending `set` has anything to do with field separation may be?

Comment: Exactly. I think about unquoted expansions as an explicit demand for pathname expansion (together with word splitting, of course); here the use is only for word splitting… it doesn't look semantically right to me (but I'm very posh).

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: Cheers! :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `cut` to print to print the second column:

```
$ echo "70.0 13.670712" | cut  -d ' ' -f2
13.670712
```

And assign that to a variable with [command substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html):

```
$ sc="$(echo '70.0 13.670712' | cut  -d ' ' -f2)"
$ echo "$sc"
13.670712
```

Just replace `echo '70.0 13.670712'` with the command that is actually producing the two numbers.

If you want to grab the last value of some delimited field (or delimited output from a command), you can use [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html). This is completely internal to Bash:

```
$ echo "$s"
$ echo ${s##*' '}
10
$ echo "$s2"
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
$ echo ${s2##*' '}
20
```

And then just assign directly:

```
$ echo "$s2"
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
$ lf=${s2##*' '}
$ echo "$lf"
20
```